# Location update function call using native Android foreground service BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, geolocation

I want to fetch current location on every 5minute when app in background for that I have created a service and broadcast receiver on native android which will call method which is in dart code, dart method will grab location and call API to update location on server.

It's working fine when I have open app but when app in background still it's calling method but can't able to read location. For location I am using Geolocator Flutter plugin.

Below function won't work inside main.dart when app is in background

```
Position userLocation = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
```

************ main.dart file

```
void widget() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  const MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel('exampleServiceChannel');
  
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Position userLocation = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();

  if (userLocation != null) {
    var url = ApiUri.updateLocation +
        "?user_id=" +
        prefs.getInt("user_id").toString() +
        "&lat=" +
        userLocation.latitude.toString() +
        "&lng=" +
        userLocation.longitude.toString();
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  }
}
```

************MainActivity Class

```
import static com.demo_employee.MyApplication.CHANNEL_ID;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity implements IServiceCallbacks {
    private Intent forService;
    static final String TAG = "Main Activity.....";
    MyService myService;
    MethodChannel channel;
    private boolean bound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startService();
    }

    public void startService() {
        String input = "Test";
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", input);
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
    }
    public void stopService(View v) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (bound) {
            myService.setCallbacks(null); // unregister
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
            bound = false;
        }
        startService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from service
        if (bound) {
            myService.setCallbacks(null); // unregister
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
            bound = false;
        }
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
        broadcastIntent.setClass(this, Restarter.class);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // display toast
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "doSomething is running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GetMethodChannel(MainActivity.this);
    }

    public static MethodChannel GetMethodChannel(Context context) {
        FlutterEngine engine = new FlutterEngine(context.getApplicationContext());

        DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint entrypoint = new DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint("lib/main.dart", "widget");

        engine.getDartExecutor().executeDartEntrypoint(entrypoint);
        return new MethodChannel(engine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL_ID);
    }

    /** Callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // cast the IBinder and get MyService instance
            MyService.LocalBinder binder = (MyService.LocalBinder) service;
            myService = binder.getService();
            bound = true;
            myService.setCallbacks(MainActivity.this); // register
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            bound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

********** MyService Class

```
import static com.test_employee.MyApplication.CHANNEL_ID;

public class MyService extends Service {
    public static final int notify = 1000 * 20;  //interval between two services(Here Service run every 20 Sec)
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();   //run on another Thread to avoid crash
    private Timer mTimer = null;    //timer handling
    private IServiceCallbacks serviceCallbacks;
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

    // Class used for the client Binder.
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        MyService getService() {
            // Return this instance of MyService so clients can call public methods
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (mTimer != null) // Cancel if already existed
            mTimer.cancel();
        else
            mTimer = new Timer();   //recreate new
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplay(), 0, notify);   //Schedule task
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Demo Service")
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mTimer.cancel();    //For Cancel Timer
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
        broadcastIntent.setClass(this, Restarter.class);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public void setCallbacks(IServiceCallbacks callbacks) {
        serviceCallbacks = callbacks;
        if (serviceCallbacks != null) {
            serviceCallbacks.doSomething();
        }
    }
    class TimeDisplay extends TimerTask {

        BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run on another thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
                    filter.addAction("INTERNET_LOST");
                    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
                    if (serviceCallbacks != null) {
                        serviceCallbacks.doSomething();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

********** MyApplication Class

```
public class MyApplication extends FlutterApplication {
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "exampleServiceChannel";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        createNotificationChannel();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Demo Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

************* Restarter class - Broadcast Receiver

```
import static com.test_employee.MyApplication.CHANNEL_ID;
public class Restarter extends BroadcastReceiver implements IServiceCallbacks {
    MyService myService;
    private boolean bound = false;
    Context _context;
    Double lat, lng;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        _context = context;
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("INTERNET_LOST"));
        Log.i("Broadcast Listened", "Service tried to stop");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Service restarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(_context, MyService.class);
        context.getApplicationContext().bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
        } else {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
        }
    }

    /** Callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // cast the IBinder and get MyService instance
            MyService.LocalBinder binder = (MyService.LocalBinder) service;
            myService = binder.getService();
            bound = true;
            myService.setCallbacks(Restarter.this); // register
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            bound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        Toast.makeText(_context, "Restarter doSomething is running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GetMethodChannel(_context);
    }

    public static MethodChannel GetMethodChannel(Context context) {
        FlutterMain.startInitialization(context);
        FlutterMain.ensureInitializationComplete(context, new String[0]);
        FlutterEngine engine = new FlutterEngine(context.getApplicationContext());
        DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint entrypoint = new DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint("lib/main.dart", "widget");
        engine.getDartExecutor().executeDartEntrypoint(entrypoint);
        return new MethodChannel(engine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL_ID);
    }
}
```